# Update Root Name Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, root

I want to update root name of an item in firebase real time database.
How to do that?

```
reference.child(Name).setValue(updateItem);
```

This code create a new item with a new name.

Comment: Are you asking how to rename an existing node? If so, this is not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+rename+node

Comment: Exactly. That's sad. Thank you very much for the answer.